# Effective way to unload data from Snowflake and update JIRA API every hour

Tags: python, pandas, jira, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We have a current setup by which a python application will pull data from SQL, put them to pandas dataframe, check for business logic and update the fields of JIRA issues.

```
issue.update(fields=update_dict)
```

I am trying to build the same application to unload Snowflake data from a table and update the fields of JIRA issues. The design approach that I was thinking of was to unload Snowflake data to S3. Use python application to load s3 file to pandas dataframes and update JIRA.

JIRA updates are required every hour. Is there any better approach to update JIRA issues every hour by fetching data from Snowflake? Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

I would consider using a `Stored Procedure` for the logic you are doing in Python (use Javascript instead until Python is available in Snowflake directly), creating an `External Function` to the JIRA API, and then scheduling the execution using a `TASK`.  This would allow everything to exist inside of Snowflake with no need for external tools or servers.

That said, I don't know the logic that you are applying in Python to fully know whether this solution is feasible, but it is worth a look.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The logic mainly revolves around comparing JIRA fields against Snowflake data. If a JIRA field is not equal to Snowflake table column, update JIRA with Snowflake table data. There are about 30 fields for comparison every time.

Comment: If you're doing that via the JIRA API to get the current field values, then you could certainly use an EXTERNAL FUNCTION for that.

Comment: Sure, let me take a look at EXTERNAL FUNCTION. Is there a way to make JIRA API calls from EXTERNAL FUNCTION?

Comment: yes, that's the purpose of an EXTERNAL FUNCTION.

Answer (score 0):

you say you have "a current setup by which a python application will pull data from SQL, put them to pandas dataframe, check for business logic and update the fields of JIRA issues". You are able to directly connect to snowflake from python with the ["snowflake-connector-python"  at link](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector.html)

If you simply swap your data source from sql to snowflake, you shouldn't have to do much different.

You can go straight to a dataframe with documentation [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-pandas.html):

```
import pandas as pd

def fetch_pandas_old(cur, sql):
    cur.execute(sql)
    rows = 0
    while True:
        dat = cur.fetchmany(50000)
        if not dat:
            break
        df = pd.DataFrame(dat, columns=cur.description)
        rows += df.shape[0]
    print(rows)
```

This example shows how to use SQLAlchemy to generate a Pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

def fetch_pandas_sqlalchemy(sql):
    rows = 0
    for chunk in pd.read_sql_query(sql, engine, chunksize=50000):
        rows += chunk.shape[0]
    print(rows)
```

Here is pure python:

```
import snowflake.connector
try
    conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
                user=USER,
                password=PASSWORD,
                account=ACCOUNT,
                warehouse=WAREHOUSE,
                database=DATABASE,
                schema=SCHEMA
                )
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('select * from products')
except Exception as ex:
   print("Failed with error {}".format(ex))
finally:
    # Closing the connection
    con.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, John ! I am aware of the above approach. My only concern was about unloading the data from Snowflake every hour to make updates to JIRA. Was curious if there is any better way to design around this.

Comment: understood, @vvazza cheers, mike, has a good response below